# auto start user(not root user) process on fedora boot

Tags: process, users, startup-scripts, fedora

I have a VM running under Fedora OS. That VM has four users lets say(A, B, C, D).
That VM has one process running under each user. So when that VM is rebooted, what should I do so that those process auto starts under respective user.

Provided that

a is the custom command to start a process under A user

b is the custom command to start a process under B user

c is the custom command to start a process under C user

d is the custom command to start a process under D user

a,b,c,d are the commands that are not available to root user. They are only available to respective users.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate Systemd init script for the processes. For process A create the file `/etc/systemd/system/A.service` and add something like this to it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Process A
After=network.target

[Service]
User=userA
Type=forking
ExecStart=/some/command/to/run --arg1 --arg2
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Customize this as you like (Restart, StartLimitInterval, StartLimitBurst, etc...)

Then enable it with

```
systemctl enable A.service
```

and start

```
systemctl start A.service
```

Comment: I must spin up a fedora vm and start learning systemd, it's heading my way in a future EL release.

Comment: Systemd is a great thing, I use it everywhere since Arch switched to it.

Comment: @stone: Do I need to make separate service file for four users?

Comment: Yes, this is the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: @stone: Fedora 18 says systemctl: command not found. Have I forgot something to install so that systemctl command can be found.

Comment: It should be there somewhere, on Arch it is in /usr/bin/systemctl but on Fedora don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the /etc/crontab and the @reboot time. The format of the /etc/crontab takes a username after the time specification and the process is run as that user.

```
@reboot A /path/to/a
@reboot B /path/tob
```

and so on.

Comment: All I want is that the process must be started whenever the server boots. Will it be possible with your answer?

Comment: @Gagan: Why not test it and see ?

Comment: @lain: What should I replace reboot with? Is reboot some kind of special variable that crontab recognize?

Comment: @lain: I have added reboot <username> <command> to crontab file but after reboot it didn't start the process. reboot has at sign infront of it.

Comment: Its a special variable, you don't need to replace it.